# Spring Micrometer - how to tag baggage in all child spans?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, micrometer, spring-micrometer

We are building an application that manages trucks.

As such, many requests include have a "truckId" field and we would like the "truckId" to be tagged in all relevant (child) spans in all of our services.

We've tried adding the baggage immediately when the request reaches our REST controller, and use ObservationFilter to append the baggage as High Cardinality values to each trace.

It works for most of the observations, but for some reason the very first observation when receiving an http request doesn't include the baggage. It seems the ObservationFilter isn't called.

I've attached code samples and the Jaeger trace image with the truckId highlighted in yellow.

We could barely find anything in the micrometer docs about it, so any help would be appreciated!

This is the client side:

```
@PostMapping("/trucks/{truckId}")
public ResponseEntity<Void> PostRequestTruckSelfCheck(@PathVariable("truckId") String truckId) {

        //* get current span
        //* Add baggage to the current span
        try (BaggageInScope baggageInScope = tracer.createBaggageInScope("truckId", truckId)) {

            HttpStatusCode code = Observation.createNotStarted("request.selfcheck.truck", observationRegistry).contextualName("handle-truck-selfcheck-request").observe(() -> selfcheckService.requestTruckSelfCheck(truckId));
            return new ResponseEntity<>(code);
        }


    }
```

And the receiving end's filter:

```
@Configuration
public class ObservabilityConfigs {
    // Monitoring beans
    @Bean
    ObservationRegistry observationRegistry(Tracer tracer) {
        ObservationRegistry observationRegistry =  ObservationRegistry.create();
        observationRegistry.observationConfig().observationFilter(new BaggageObservationFilter(tracer));
        return observationRegistry;
    }

    // To have the @Observed support we need to register this aspect
    @Bean
    ObservedAspect observedAspect(ObservationRegistry observationRegistry) {
        return new ObservedAspect(observationRegistry);
    }


    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public static class BaggageObservationFilter implements ObservationFilter {
        private final Tracer tracer;

        @Override
        @NonNull
        public Observation.Context map(Observation.Context context) {
            //* add baggage to the context
            tracer.getAllBaggage().entrySet().stream().map(entry -> KeyValue.of(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())).forEach(context::addHighCardinalityKeyValue);
            return context;
        }

    }
```

[image]